# Classic snaps not working

Tags: package-management, snap

I tried installing alacritty through snap, and all was well.
But when i run it i get this error message

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to initialize any backend!
    Wayland status: NoCompositorListening
    X11 status: LibraryOpenError(
    OpenError {
        kind: Library,
        detail: "opening library failed (/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26\' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6)); opening library failed (/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26\' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so))"
    }
)
', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/winit-0.15.1/src/platform/linux/mod.rs:428:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 with kernel 5.3.0-40-generic

Comment: On Ubuntu (Default) not Wayland, Intellij-Idea and PyCharm are working, but alacritty does not start with the same error.

Comment: Same here, 2020, Ubuntu 20. Someone should tell the snap maintainer that the snap is broken, the Alacritty team just washed their hands off it saying it's not their issue.